# SOAP message deserialization issue in WCF - fields have null values

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, soap

Here's my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Service.Namespace)]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use=OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    UpdateResponse Update(UpdateRequest request);
}
```

The implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = Namespace)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public const string Namespace = "http://schemas.localhost.net/test";

    public UpdateResponse Update(UpdateRequest request)
    {
        return new UpdateResponse() { Succeeded = true };
    }
}
```

The message contracts:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = Service.Namespace)]
public class UpdateRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = Service.Namespace)]
public class UpdateResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
}
```

The web.config file (a part of it):

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults" name="ServiceTest.Service">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceTest.IService" 
              bindingNamespace="http://schemas.localhost.net/test" />
  </service>
</services>
```

And here is the soap message (request) sent from fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:10000/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.localhost.net/test/IService/Update"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Host: localhost:10000
Content-Length: 532

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.localhost.net/test">       
    <NS1:UpdateRequest id="1">  
        <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Abcdefg</Name><Id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Id>
    </NS1:UpdateRequest>
    <parameters href="#1"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Update() operation receives an UpdateRequest object, but **the fields are not set (Name is null, Id is zero)**. The response is ok, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name and Id elements don't have namespace. So either the soap envelope is not correct, or the MessageContract is not complete. The Name/Id should look like:

```
<NS1:Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Abcdefg</NS1:Name><NS1:Id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</NS1:Id>
```

Comment: Not quite sure. To inherit, you'll need xmlns="namespace". Here it is defined as NS1, not default, hence not inherited.

Comment: I stand corrected, that indeed only applies to the default namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the **XmlSerializer** :) 
But i did not decorate the members of the message with the following **attribute**:

```
[XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified), MessageBodyMember]
```

The deserialization works now.

PS: I couldn't do what Tisho said because I don't control the client of the web service.