# Using nested complex types in SOAP Message - WCF XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I recently posted a question on StackOverflow:

[SOAP message deserialization issue in WCF - fields have null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754027/soap-message-deserialization-issue-in-wcf-fields-have-null-values)

It was something about one of the WCF serialization engines, `XmlSerializer`, used to serialize/deserialize SOAP messages. The deserialization didn't work at first - some namespace issues.

Back to present :)

Fields decorated with `[XmlElement, MessageBodyMember]` are deserialized fine now if they are **simple types**.

There is a problem regarding **custom types**: they are set, but their fields have null values :(

Is there a configuration I should make on the XmlSerializer?

```
[MessageContract]
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified), MessageBodyMember]
    public XType X { get; set; }
}

[what to write here?]
public class XType
{
    [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified), body member?]
    public string AString { get; set; }

    ... maybe another nested complex objects
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the XmlSerializer? Do you have to use it? It's old and out of date.

Comment: XmlSerializer it's a little more configurable that DataContractSerializer in terms of namespace scoping etc (as far as I know) - for example, I needed that "XmlSchemaForm = Unqualified" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had those serialization problems because the client of the service has a serialization engine that is not "compatible" with the ones that WCF uses. The request was still standard XML, of course (SOAP 1.2), but hey, WCF is a Microsoft product :)

Some workarounds:

- Add a **MessageFormater** - that implements some deserialization logic at the server side - a good [article](http://keyvan.io/use-idispatchmessageformatter-and-iclientmessageformatter-to-customize-messages-in-wcf) about that;
- Add a **MessageInspector** - that reads the SOAP request and does some XML formatting (so that the deserialization will work fine) - you can read about it following [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx).